# Minimal detectable change based on >2 measurements

Tags: reliability

I need to calculate the minimal detectable change (MDC) for my dataset and found the following formula in several publications:

$MDC = 1.96 * SD * \sqrt(1-ICC) * \sqrt2$

They argue $\sqrt2$ is used, because of the uncertainty of two measurement timepoints. 
However, in my dataset I don't have just test-retest measurement, but indeed 7 different measurement timepoints, based on which I need to calculate the MDC. Do I need to exchange $\sqrt2$ by $\sqrt7$?

Comment: Are you trying to find one MDC (e.g. MDC between measurement 1 and 7) or 6 MDCs (MDC for 1 to 2, 2 to 3 etc.)?

Comment: I am trying to find one MDC based on the data of 7 different measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need to change $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{7}$.

With more observations for a subject, it is easier to detect a change. Therefore $MDC_7 \le MDC_2$.

Recall that the $\sqrt{2}$ is an adjustment for a small number of observations. Therefore, we need to use $MDC = 1.96*SD*\sqrt{1-ICC}$.